# Change image every 10 second

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change image every 10 seconds in javascript, can someone help me?

Here's the images, I only want add some code on javascript without changing these code below

**HTML**

```
<body onload = "imageChanger()">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><img src = "images/img1.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src = "images/img2.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src = "images/img3.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src = "images/img4.jpg"/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
div {margin: 50px auto; height: 500px; width: 800px; overflow: hidden; border: 10px solid;}
img {width: 800px; height: 500px;}
ul {list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
```

I want to add some code that will change image on load:

**JS**

```
function imageChanger()
{
    //Code here
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your attempts. I suggest looking into the `setInterval()` function

Comment: look at any image slider on the internet: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+image+slider

Comment: `var i = 0;setInterval(function() { $('li:eq(' + ( i++ % 4) + ')'.show().siblings().hide(); }, 10000);`

Comment: @Tushar. just answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did for a similar scenario.

```
<body id="background">
<script>
$(function () { 
    var imageArray = ['BG-1.jpg', 'BG-2.jpg', 'BG-3.jpg', 'BG-4.jpg', 'BG-5.jpg', 'BG-6.jpg', 'BG-7.jpg', 'BG-8.jpg', 'BG-9.jpg', 'BG-10.jpg', 'BG-11.jpg', 'BG-12.jpg', 'BG-13.jpg', 'BG-14.jpg', 'BG-15.jpg', 'BG-16.jpg', 'BG-17.jpg', 'BG-18.jpg', 'BG-19.jpg', 'BG-20.jpg', 'BG-21.jpg', 'BG-22.jpg'] 

// on page load
$('#background').css({ 'background-image': 'url(/Content/img/BackGround/' + imageArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imageArray.length)] + ')', 'background-size': 'cover' })

// every 10 seconds change to random image name in the array
setInterval(function () { 
    $('#background').css({ 'background-image': 'url(/Content/img/BackGround/' + imageArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imageArray.length)] + ')', 'background-size': 'cover' }) 
    }, 10000); 
});
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval()` for this.

**Code**

```
var i = 0;

setInterval(changeImage, 10000);
changeImage(); //Initial call to hide the images on start

function changeImage() {
    i = (i + 1) % $('li').length; //Make sure the list wraps back to 0

    $('li:eq(' + i + ')').show().siblings().hide();
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gL9sjy5/1/)

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Just claiming it doesn't work doesn't help us help you solve your issue